# Isometric Operators: Common Core

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

Given a Hilbert or Banach space $\mathcal{H}$.

Consider two closed operators $S:\mathcal{D}(S)\to\mathcal{H}$ and $T:\mathcal{D}(T)\to\mathcal{H}$.

Suppose they're isometric on a common core $\mathcal{D}$:
$$\|Sz\|=\|Tz\|\quad z\in\mathcal{D}$$
Then they already had a common domain $\mathcal{D}(S)=\mathcal{D}(T)$.

Especially they're isometric:
$$\|Sx\|=\|Tx\|\quad x\in\mathcal{D}(S)=\mathcal{D}(T)$$

That is a simple limiting argument but how do I prove that they had a common domain?

Comment: What is the definition of a "common core"?

Comment: It is a core for both operators.

Comment: Ok, what is a "core" of an operator? :) I could of course look it up, but if you mention it in the post, it makes it easier for people to understand & answer your question. :)

Comment: If the common core included the content of this question it would really be something.

Comment: @PhoemueX: I'm sorry I was out last night. Do you still need some help about the definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now looked up the definition of a core of an operator and it could be that the answer actually depends on the **exact** definition.

In Wikipedia, a core (of a closed operator) is defined as a sub**set** $D$ of the domain of $A$ such that $A$ is the closure of $A|D$.

If we replace this by requiring that $D$ be a sub**space**, I can prove your claim.

By symmetry, it suffices to show $D(S) \subset D(T)$.

Let $x\in D(S)$ be arbitrary. There is a sequence $(x_n)_n$ in $D$ with $(x_n, Sx_n) \to (x,Sx)$. Hence,

$$
\Vert Tx_n - Tx_m \Vert = \Vert T (x_n - x_m)\Vert = \Vert Sx_n - Sx_m \Vert \to 0
$$

for $n,m \to \infty$. Here I used $x_n - x_m \in D$, because $D$ is a sub**space**.

As we are working on Banach spaces, this yields $(x_n, Tx_n) \to (x,y)$ for some $y$. But $T$ is assumed closed, which in particular yields $x \in D(T)$.

Comment: Nice thanks. :)